# Plolymorphism in a nutshell

Tags: polymorphism

Im going to try and keep this real basic, but I want to make sure my understanding of polymorphism is correct...using a basic example. Dont judge my actual code as I'm just starting out with Java ;)

I have a base class "Animal" and 2 subclasses "Tiger" and "Turtle".  Animal has a method Feed().  both Tiger and Turtle impement Feed() with their own instructions.

If i have a program called ZooKeeperTasks and in that program I have the following code

```
// animals[] is an array of Animal. 
// assume that it contains both tigers and turtles
{
    for(int i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
        animals[i].Feed();
    }
}
```

Isnt this polymorphism in a nutshell??  Calling feed without knowing the actual datatype of the array elements?

Comment: Why not add the classes to the code example? Then it would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism is the ability of an object to take on different forms. So, your example is a good example of polymorphism, but not because you can call the method without knowing the data type, but because your parent class(animal) is referring to the children class objects[poly = many] (tiger and turtle) and alter them [morph = change].